# How can I deploy spark artifacts to a custom maven repository?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a fork of apache spark on github that I build from. 
I have a maven repository that our company uses to manage dependencies.
Suppose the url of this maven repository is https://xyz.abc.com/maven.
If I run a command like

```
./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.5 -DskipTests install
```

Then all the jars get deployed to my local maven repository, but what I would really like is for them to be deployed to the repository mentioned above.
How can I do that? Do I need to modify certain files or set environment variables? Do I need to add a credential file somewhere?
I also looked into doing it with sbt, but I could not figure out how to do it with that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [publish](https://www.apache.org/dev/publishing-maven-artifacts.html) artifact build by maven to remote repository (https://xyz.abc.com/maven).

Take a look at [this guide](http://www.baeldung.com/maven-deploy-nexus) for required configuration.

Comment: I don't think our maven repository is a nexus repository. Does it have to be Nexus?

Comment: No, it should not. General configuration steps are going to be the same. Take a look at documentation of your server, they can have some specific details.